# Adding the Gantry font sizer feature to the RocketTheme Afterburner2 template

Tags: joomla3.1

I use a customized version of the RocketTheme Afterburner2 template. The Afterburner2 template is based on the Gantry framework and has been stripped of of all unnecessary features in order to obtain a very fast template.

I am novice in using the Gantry framework. I would like to reintegrate in my template the Gantry font sizer feature, but don't see how to do it.

Thanks for your help or for pointing me the right documentation.

Jean-Pierre

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely a simple task to re-enable this feature in Afterburner but you could add another extension to do this for you such as the non-commercial jFontSize module:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/accessibility/24328

Alternatively, you could switch to the default Gantry template which is reasonably lean but still has the font sizer feature included.